# How to use Postman for FromUri request parameters?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have written the below simple Web API method.

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public int SumNumbers([FromUri]Numbers calc, [FromUri]Operation op)
{
    int result = op.Add ? calc.First + calc.Second : calc.First - calc.Second;
    return op.Double ? result * 2 : result;
}
```

Below is the model class for Numbers:

```
public class Numbers
{
    public int First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the model class for Operation:

```
public class Operation
{
    public bool Add { get; set; }
    public bool Double { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am not understanding how to use Postman to check this Web API method.

I have tried like below, but not working. I am not getting any error, but I am not getting response. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the values on the header but using the URI in your code. You would need either to change your code OR the way you send the request with Postman.

As far as I can see you'd need to add the values to your URI as part of the query string:

```
http://localhost:29844/api/bindings/SumNumbers?first=10&second=20&add=true&double=false
```

[Have a look at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri)

Comment: I want some way to do using Postman. Could you please narrate me to use Postman!

Comment: I literally just did. You either change your code to accept those headers you're sending with postman in your screenshot or use the simple get request.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but still NOT working for me. I am still getting 0 as result.

Comment: can you try this? `http://localhost:29844/api/bindings/SumNumbers?first=10&second=20&add=true&double=false`

Comment: Thank you Alex, yes, it is working. But, I am unable to debug the code. Any suggestion on how can I debug the code with the above URL?

Comment: Sure, use the debugger. But that's out of the scope of this question, this was related to Postman. Is your Postman question solved?